# QGIS shuts down when executing PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm new to PyQGIS. I have some simple PyQGIS scripts.

The only one that I use a bool input doesn't work. Whenever I execute it, QGIS shuts down.

I see that the reason is 'qgis killed by SIGABRT' but I have no idea what it is. Could you please take a look if there're some mistakes in my code or it's about the QGIS/Python package? I'm on QGIS 3.10 sur fedora

```
class algTest(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    OUTPUT_TABLES = 'OUTPUT_TABLES'
    CITY = 'CITY'
    INPUT_LINE_CITY= 'INPUT_LINE_CITY'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def name(self):
        return "download_line_bool"

    def displayName(self):
        return "download lines with city bool"

    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString(
            self.CITY, "Input City"))

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterBoolean (
                self.INPUT_LINE_CITY,
                'Only City'
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination (
                self.OUTPUT_TABLES,
                'Output layer'
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        my_city = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.CITY, context)
        my_bool = self.parameterAsBool(parameters, self.INPUT_LINE_CITY, context)
        uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
        uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "***", "***", "***")

        if my_bool == True:
            uri.setDataSource("public", "transport_public", "the_geom", "city='"+my_city+"'","id")
        else:
            uri.setDataSource("public", "transport_public", "the_geom", "","id")
        table = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "table", "postgres")
        return {self.OUTPUT_TABLES:table}
```